# Cisco XR Interfaces

Tags: cisco, ios

I'm trying to figure out if a device which is running Cisco IOS XR is affected.

The advisory is published [here](http://www.cisco.com/warp/public/707/cisco-sa-20110525-iosxr.shtml)

Assuming I have the vulnerable OS versions, Now I want to check if I have a Cisco Line Card or Cisco CRS MSC with IPv4 address configured on one of the interfaces, how do I check that from the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advisory is basically saying that if you have any IPv4 addresses configured on any of the ports, you're vulnerable.  In other words, if this router connects to the internet at all, you're most likely vulnerable to attacks and need to use either a workaround or upgrade to code that has a bug fix in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an IOS-XR specialist, but on "classical" IOS, you can see the ipv4 addresses on interfaces like this :

```
r01#show ip interface brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            172.23.14.253   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
FastEthernet0/1            unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    down
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I know if it belongs to a MSC or some Line Card? (I'm not a cisco expert at all)